# xml parsing with js - differentiating 2 elements with same name but different parent

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing

How can we apply this [example of xml parser](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp) in case there are 2 elements with the same name but of different kind?
Example:

```xml
<Dbtr>
    <Nm>Debtor</Nm>
</Dbtr>
<Cdtr>
    <Nm>Creditor</Nm>
</Cdtr>
```

How can I differentiate both names?

Comment: "Parsing" is not the correct word; that's the work that the XML parser does to create a DOM from the XML source. Via the constructed DOM, you can use the fact that the structure implies the meaning of the `<Nm>` tag contents. With something like xpath, you can select content via paths through the structure.

Comment: Please try this script in your provided w3schools links:
<script>
var parser, xmlDoc;
var text = "<Dbtr>"+
    "<Nm>Debtor</Nm>"+
"</Dbtr>"+
"<Cdtr>"+
    "<Nm>Creditor</Nm>"+
"</Cdtr>";

parser = new DOMParser();
  const parsedDocument =
                parser.parseFromString(
                text, "text/html");
  var allText = parsedDocument
                .all[0].getElementsByTagName('nm')[1].innerHTML;
   console.log(allText);
</script>

Answer (score 0):

After parsing the XML<sup>1</sup>, a selector can a node based on its parent:

### Using a selector

```js
const xml = `
<root>
  <Dbtr>
      <Nm>Debtor</Nm>
  </Dbtr>
  <Cdtr>
      <Nm>Creditor</Nm>
  </Cdtr>
</root>
`;

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, "application/xml");

const debitor  = doc.querySelector("Dbtr > Nm").textContent;
const creditor = doc.querySelector("Cdtr > Nm").textContent;

console.log(debitor);
console.log(creditor);
```

See more:

- [Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors)

### Using XPath

Alternatively, XPath can be used in the same manner:

```js
const xml = `
<root>
  <Dbtr>
      <Nm>Debtor</Nm>
  </Dbtr>
  <Cdtr>
      <Nm>Creditor</Nm>
  </Cdtr>
</root>
`;

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, "application/xml");

const debitorNode = doc.evaluate(
  "//Dbtr/Nm",
  doc,
  null,
  XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
  null
).singleNodeValue;

const creditorNode = doc.evaluate(
  "//Cdtr/Nm",
  doc,
  null,
  XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
  null
).singleNodeValue

const debitor  = debitorNode.textContent;
const creditor = creditorNode.textContent;

console.log(debitor);
console.log(creditor);
```

See more:

- [`document.evaluate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate)
- and [using it with XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript#document.evaluate)

---

<sup>1</sup>Note: XML documents need to have a single top-level node.

Comment: Hi VLAZ. Thanks a lot. The first option seems easier. Any advantage in using one rather than the other?

Comment: @NALL well, you can use XPath with it. So, if you have some prepared XPath snippets, you can run them. Also, allows for some slightly different ways to traverse the DOM, that might not be available with selectors. Other than that, it allows for some more complex processing of results. With all that said, it's probably an overkill in this case. It's useful tool to know of, so I'm just showing it exists. I'd personally just stick to selectors for something as simple as this.